# Showing that $[\mathbb C(z):\mathbb C(f_0)]=$topological degree of $f_0\in\mathbb C(z)$ as a function from the Riemann sphere to itself

Tags: complex-analysis, galois-theory

[McKean & Moll](http://books.google.com/books?id=CDP1zxFJLucC&lpg=PA10&dq=mckean%20moll%20luroth&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q&f=false) offer the following sketch of a proof.

Let $P(x)=a_0(x)-f_0b_0(x)$ in $\mathbb C(f_0)[x]$ where $f_0(z)=\dfrac{a_0(z)}{b_0(z)}$ is in $\mathbb C(z)$. Then evidently, $\deg P=\#$ poles of $f_0=$ topological degree of $f_0$ as it extends to a map from $\mathbb P^1\to\mathbb P^1$. Hence, $d=[\mathbb C(z):\mathbb C(f_0)]\leq\deg P=$topological degree of $f_0$.
On the other hand, let $P_0=x^d+s_1x^{d-1}+\dots s_d$ be the minimal polynomial of $z$ over $\mathbb C(f_0)$. Clearly (or it is not hard to check that) only finitely many $c\in\mathbb C$ are poles of some $s_i$ or such that $f(z)=c$ has repeated roots.

So far so good, but then comes the claim I can't prove.

**Claim.** If $f(z)=c$ has only simple roots (and so $d_0=$topological degree of $f_0$ of them), then $x^d+s_1(c)x^{d-1}+\dots s_d(c)$ vanishes on each of those simple roots (where $s_i(c)$ is the image of $s_i$ under the map that takes $f_0\to c$ in $\mathbb C(f_0)$; the $s_i$ being rational functions of $f_0$).

I see why wherever $x^d+s_1(c)x^{d-1}+\dots s_d(c)$, we have a root of $f(z)=c$, but I don't see what the converse would follow from at all. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to show P(x) is irreducible in C(f_0)[x].Irreducibility there is the same as irreducibility in the ring C[f_0][x]. Now write that ring as C[x][f_0] and think a little...

Comment: Thanks, that does prove $P$ irreducible. But if I am reading the book correctly, I think McKean & Moll are trying to bypass Gauss' Lemma via the geometry, since if $P$ is irreducible, then $[\mathbb C(z):\mathbb C(f_0)]$=degree of $P_0$=degree of $P$ = topological degree of $f_0$, and none of the argument they present (except the last equality) is necessary.